# How to filter list of all users currently signed up for app to implement a sort of inbox

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a messaging app for Android and am attempting to filter my user list that currently shows all signed up users.  I am using Parse.  I would like to query the Parse database to filter the list of all users to only show users that you have current conversations with.  So, some sort of inbox scenario.  I am fairly new to android development and would appreciate some help implementing this logic.  I've been scouring the internet (including stack overflow) for the past 24 hours and finally caved in and tried my luck here.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

UserList.java

```
public class UserList extends CustomActivity
{

/** The Chat list. */
private ArrayList<ParseUser> uList;

/** The user. */
public static ParseUser user;

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    setContentView(R.layout.user_list);


    updateUserStatus(true);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onDestroy()
 */
@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    updateUserStatus(false);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onResume()
 */
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    loadUserList();

}

/**
 * Update user status.
 *
 * @param online
 *            true if user is online
 */
private void updateUserStatus(boolean online)
{
    user.put("online", online);
    user.saveEventually();
}

/**
 * Load list of users.
 */
private void loadUserList()
{
    final ProgressDialog dia = ProgressDialog.show(this, null,
            getString(R.string.alert_loading));
    ParseUser.getQuery().whereNotEqualTo("username", user.getUsername())
            .findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseUser> li, ParseException e) {
                    dia.dismiss();
                    if (li != null) {
                        if (li.size() == 0)
                            Toast.makeText(UserList.this,
                                    R.string.msg_no_user_found,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        uList = new ArrayList<ParseUser>(li);
                        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                        list.setAdapter(new UserAdapter());
                        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                                    View arg1, int pos, long arg3) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(UserList.this,
                                        Chat.class).putExtra(
                                        Const.EXTRA_DATA, uList.get(pos)
                                                .getUsername()));
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        Utils.showDialog(
                                UserList.this,
                                getString(R.string.err_users) + " "
                                        + e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
}

/**
 * The Class UserAdapter is the adapter class for User ListView. This
 * adapter shows the user name and it's only online status for each item.
 */
private class UserAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getCount()
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return uList.size();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getItem(int)
     */
    @Override
    public ParseUser getItem(int arg0)
    {
        return uList.get(arg0);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getItemId(int)
     */
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0)
    {
        return arg0;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getView(int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View v, ViewGroup arg2)
    {
        if (v == null)
            v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.chat_item, null);

        ParseUser c = getItem(pos);
        TextView lbl = (TextView) v;
        lbl.setText(c.getUsername());
        lbl.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                c.getBoolean("online") ? R.drawable.ic_online
                        : R.drawable.ic_offline, 0, R.drawable.arrow, 0);

        return v;
    }

}
}
```

Conversation.java

```
public class Conversation
{

/** The Constant STATUS_SENDING. */
public static final int STATUS_SENDING = 0;

/** The Constant STATUS_SENT. */
public static final int STATUS_SENT = 1;

/** The Constant STATUS_FAILED. */
public static final int STATUS_FAILED = 2;
/** The msg. */
private String msg;

/** The status. */
private int status = STATUS_SENT;

/** The date. */
private Date date;

/** The sender. */
private String sender;

/**
 * Instantiates a new conversation.
 * 
 * @param msg
 *            the msg
 * @param date
 *            the date
 * @param sender
 *            the sender
 */
public Conversation(String msg, Date date, String sender)
{
    this.msg = msg;
    this.date = date;
    this.sender = sender;
}

/**
 * Instantiates a new conversation.
 */
public Conversation()
{
}

/**
 * Gets the msg.
 * 
 * @return the msg
 */
public String getMsg()
{
    return msg;
}

/**
 * Sets the msg.
 * 
 * @param msg
 *            the new msg
 */
public void setMsg(String msg)
{
    this.msg = msg;
}

/**
 * Checks if is sent.
 * 
 * @return true, if is sent
 */
public boolean isSent()
{
    return UserList.user.getUsername().equals(sender);
}

/**
 * Gets the date.
 * 
 * @return the date
 */
public Date getDate()
{
    return date;
}

/**
 * Sets the date.
 * 
 * @param date
 *            the new date
 */
public void setDate(Date date)
{
    this.date = date;
}

/**
 * Gets the sender.
 * 
 * @return the sender
 */
public String getSender()
{
    return sender;
}

/**
 * Sets the sender.
 * 
 * @param sender
 *            the new sender
 */
public void setSender(String sender)
{
    this.sender = sender;
}

/**
 * Gets the status.
 * 
 * @return the status
 */
public int getStatus()
{
    return status;
}

/**
 * Sets the status.
 * 
 * @param status
 *            the new status
 */
public void setStatus(int status)
{
    this.status = status;
}

}
```

Chat.java

```
public class Chat extends CustomActivity
{

/** The Conversation list. */
private ArrayList<Conversation> convList;

/** The chat adapter. */
private ChatAdapter adp;

/** The Editext to compose the message. */
private EditText txt;

/** The user name of buddy. */
private String buddy;

/** The date of last message in conversation. */
private Date lastMsgDate;

/** Flag to hold if the activity is running or not. */
private boolean isRunning;

/** The handler. */
private static Handler handler;

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chat);

    convList = new ArrayList<Conversation>();
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adp = new ChatAdapter();
    list.setAdapter(adp);
    list.setTranscriptMode(AbsListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
    list.setStackFromBottom(true);

    txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    txt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
            | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);

    setTouchNClick(R.id.btnSend);

    buddy = getIntent().getStringExtra(Const.EXTRA_DATA);
    getActionBar().setTitle(buddy);

    handler = new Handler();
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onResume()
 */
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    isRunning = true;
    loadConversationList();
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onPause()
 */
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    isRunning = false;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.socialshare.custom.CustomFragment#onClick(android.view.View)
 */
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    super.onClick(v);
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnSend)
    {
        sendMessage();
    }

}

/**
 * Call this method to Send message to other person. It does nothing if the text
 * is empty otherwise it creates a Parse object for Chat message and send it
 * to Parse server.
 */
private void sendMessage()
{
    if (txt.length() == 0)
        return;

    String s = txt.getText().toString();
    final Conversation c = new Conversation(s, new Date(),
            UserList.user.getUsername());
    c.setStatus(Conversation.STATUS_SENDING);
    convList.add(c);
    adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
    txt.setText(null);

    ParseObject po = new ParseObject("Chat");
    po.put("sender", UserList.user.getUsername());
    po.put("receiver", buddy);
    // po.put("createdAt", "");
    po.put("message", s);
    po.saveEventually(new SaveCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e)
        {
            if (e == null)
                c.setStatus(Conversation.STATUS_SENT);
            else
                c.setStatus(Conversation.STATUS_FAILED);
            adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Load the conversation list from Parse server and save the date of last
 * message that will be used to load only recent new messages
 */
private void loadConversationList()
{
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> q = ParseQuery.getQuery("Chat");
    if (convList.size() == 0)
    {
        // load all messages...
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
        al.add(buddy);
        al.add(UserList.user.getUsername());
        q.whereContainedIn("sender", al);
        q.whereContainedIn("receiver", al);
    }
    else
    {
        // load only newly received message..
        if (lastMsgDate != null)
            q.whereGreaterThan("createdAt", lastMsgDate);
        q.whereEqualTo("sender", buddy);
        q.whereEqualTo("receiver", UserList.user.getUsername());
    }
    q.orderByDescending("createdAt");
    q.setLimit(30);
    q.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> li, ParseException e)
        {
            if (li != null && li.size() > 0)
            {
                for (int i = li.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    ParseObject po = li.get(i);
                    Conversation c = new Conversation(po
                            .getString("message"), po.getCreatedAt(), po
                            .getString("sender"));
                    convList.add(c);
                    if (lastMsgDate == null
                            || lastMsgDate.before(c.getDate()))
                        lastMsgDate = c.getDate();
                    adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    if (isRunning)
                        loadConversationList();
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    });

}

/**
 * The Class ChatAdapter is the adapter class for Chat ListView. This
 * adapter shows the Sent or Receieved Chat message in each list item.
 */
private class ChatAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getCount()
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return convList.size();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getItem(int)
     */
    @Override
    public Conversation getItem(int arg0)
    {
        return convList.get(arg0);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getItemId(int)
     */
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0)
    {
        return arg0;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getView(int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View v, ViewGroup arg2)
    {
        Conversation c = getItem(pos);
        if (c.isSent())
            v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.chat_item_sent, null);
        else
            v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.chat_item_rcv, null);

        TextView lbl = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lbl1);
        lbl.setText(DateUtils.getRelativeDateTimeString(Chat.this, c
                .getDate().getTime(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS,
                DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS, 0));

        lbl = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lbl2);
        lbl.setText(c.getMsg());

        lbl = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lbl3);
        if (c.isSent())
        {
            if (c.getStatus() == Conversation.STATUS_SENT)
                lbl.setText("Delivered");
            else if (c.getStatus() == Conversation.STATUS_SENDING)
                lbl.setText("Sending...");
            else
                lbl.setText("Failed");
        }
        else
            lbl.setText("");

        return v;
    }

}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)
 */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home)
    {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thanks for posting your code. It's not entirely clear, though, what your question is. Are you asking how to *query* the Parse database, or how to display the results, or...?

Comment: It may be helpful to review [ask] and [mcve]. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you sir.  Yes, I am asking how to query the Parse database to filter the list of all users to only show users that you have current conversations with.  So some sort of "inbox" experience for the user.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm not familiar with Parse, but I think it'd be worthwhile to edit your question to make it clear that you are asking about querying. It sounds like you're asking an Android-specific question but if I'm understanding correctly, it really doesn't have anything to do with Android.